# PHP - как сгруппировать в массиве по значению?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
Array ( [0] => DCH_TRANS
        [1] => DirectoryName=/home/1 
        [2] => EDR_S1 
        [3] => DirectoryName=/dirs1/fid
        [4] => FM_12 
        [5] => DirectoryName=/dir/dir/2 
        [6] => FM_12
        [7] => DirectoryName=/dir/dir/3 
        [8] => FM_12
        [9] => DestinationDir=/pack/dir
        [10] => FM_156
        [11] => DestinationDir=/pack/dir
        [12] => DirectoryName=/dir/dir/3 
        )
```

Как можно сделать группировку по значению элемента, если он не содержит DirectoryName или DestinationDir ? Т.е нужно оставить только первое значение данного элемента.

Пробовал разбить на 2 массива и убрать в первом дубли через array_uniq, то не понял как обратно их соединить. Или может быть здесь можно просто через сравнение с предыдущим значением это делать. Прошу помочь.

В итоге должно получиться:

```
Array ( [0] => DCH_TRANS
        [1] => DirectoryName=/home/1 
        [2] => EDR_S1 
        [3] => DirectoryName=/dirs1/fid
        [4] => FM_12 
        [5] => DirectoryName=/dir/dir/2 
        [6] => DirectoryName=/dir/dir/3 
        [7] => DestinationDir=/pack/dir
        [8] => FM_156
        [9] => DestinationDir=/pack/dir
        [10] => DirectoryName=/dir/dir/3 
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обходим массив и значения из него в соответствии с вашей логикой переносим в новый

```
$target = [];
foreach ($source as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, 'DestinationDir') !== false 
        || strpos($value, 'DirectoryName') !== false) {
        $target[] = $value;
    } else {
        if (!in_array($value, $target)) { // вставляем в новый массив только если нет такого значения
            $target[] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```